# Webpack dev server doesnt show full url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, webpack

I am launching my app via webpack-dev-server but instead of full url like e.g: http://localhost:8080/welcome webpack always show me http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server. Is there any options to change it ?

This is my webpack config:

```
var loaders = require("./loaders");
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  debug: true,
  entry: ['./app/main.ts',],
  output: {
    filename: './dist/build.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json']
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      'window.jquery': 'jquery'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: loaders
  },
  externals: {
    'angular': 'angular',
    'lodash': '_'
  }
};
```

These are my loaders:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
    loader: 'ts-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'ngtemplate?relativeTo=/src/!html'
  },
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.less$/,
    loader: 'style!css!less'
  },
  {
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
  },
  {
    test: '\.jpg$',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'file'
  },
  {
    test: '\.png$',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'url'
  }
];
```

Comment: Could you please share your webpack config that you're using?

Comment: This is my webpack config.

Comment: There is also some `loaders` which probably contains configuration for dev server, could you please find related one and share it too?

Comment: how are you running your app? can you share that part too?

Comment: npm run start where start is :  "start": "webpack-dev-server",

Answer (score 0):

By default go to localhost:8080/ to launch your app. If you are using i-frame mode then it will got to http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server. If you want to run your app through localhost:8080 then set publicPath to `'/'` in output

```
output: {
    filename: './dist/build.js',
    publicPath:"/"   
}
```

and in your package.json

```
"start":"webpack-dev-server"
```

Comment: But when I go to another page the url is still the same ;/ Always http://localhost:8080/welcome .

Comment: that is something to do with routing webpack-dev-server is only serving you the application what is in url is depends on your routing. what kind of routing you are using?

Comment: "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2", and html part is <a [routerLink]="['/products']">TEST</a>

Comment: OK, i guess that is not only routing there should be like welcome some where, however this issue is not related to webpack-dev-server but to angular routing. please update your question with regarding this new information.

Comment: It is webpack fault because earlier itwas working good. When I add webpack it failed.

Comment: Have you tried with any other server like lite-server or live-server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122446/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-user3528733).